# How to resolve ResourceErrorCode: 400 when deploying a firewall resource with Google Cloud Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to deploy a single firewall resource with Google Cloud Deployment Manager. I want the firewall to block just my own ip address from accessing my App Engine app that is already deployed at https://cloudfunctiongateway.uc.r.appspot.com/. However, I am getting an error:

```
  location: /deployments/firewall-deployment2/resources/app-firewall
  message: '{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.firewall","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Request
    contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad
    Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cloudfunctiongateway/global/firewalls","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

Here is my config file in `firewall.yaml`:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: app-firewall
  properties:
    network: https://cloudfunctiongateway.uc.r.appspot.com/
    denied:
      - IPProtocol: 33.27.10.123 # a fake ip address, I use my real one
    sourceRanges: [ 0.0.0.0/0 ]
```

And I am running this command in the same directory:

`gcloud deployment-manager deployments create firewall-deployment --config firewall.yaml`

I have even tried to deploy with just this in my config file:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.firewall
  name: app-firewall
```

But still get the same error message. Any way to fix this? Note I want to be able to do this with Deployment Manager. I already know I can manually setup a firewall from the App Engine Dashboard.

Comment: I believe the issue is with the `network` field. That field should be the url or selfLink of the network where the firewall rule is to be applied. The second resource you made does not have a definition so it can't be created either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need is to create a [firewall rule for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls) application which is a different thing from the GCP Firewall - those are two different things.

So - in order to do this try running this:

```
resources:
- name: dmapprule1
  type: gcp-types/appengine-v1:apps.firewall.ingressRules
  properties:
    appsId: 00c61b117c74f1a3bbcb4900df618a4c4ae211790ade0822a63cb492d671f318776a5a
    priority: 1000
    action: "DENY"
    source_range: "0.0.0.0/0"
```

and run it with `gcloud deployment-manager deployments create firewall-deployment --config firewall.yaml`

### UPDATE

To see a full list of supported types use `gcloud beta deployment-manager types list` (beta version list is much more comprehensive).

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, how did you know what the resource type value should be? When I use the ```gcloud deployment-manager types list``` command suggested in the docs, I don't see this appengine firewall resource type listed.